# copying data to data structure using memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to read data from EEPROM, and I have three structs.

```
typedef struct
{
    fract32 MechCoilPhiBase;    // Mech Angle Table
    fract32 MechCoilPhi3rd;    // Mech Angle Table
    fract32 PhiSaltwater;       // Saltwater Table
    UINT16  d;
    UINT16  crc;
} ChannelData_T;

typedef struct
{

    UINT32 reHarmonic;
    UINT32 reFundamental;
    UINT32 imgHarmonic;
    UINT32 imgFundamental;

    UINT16 crc;
} CoilBoard_T;

// mechanic angles and salt water angles of coil stored in coil-eeprom
typedef struct
{
    ChannelData_T channel[NUM_CHANNELS];
    CoilBoard_T   coilboard;
//  UINT32    gCoilSerialNumber;
//  UINT32    gInversSerialNumber;
} Coil_Eeprom_Data_T;
```

I'm trying to read the data, but the size is not a power of 2, I tried to padding the data, but the struct is not filled correctly.

I'm using the following code to read the data from the buffer, and fill it with the struct. 
For example the crc variable is 0, and its not read correctly from the buffer.

here is how I copy the data to the buffer

```
 memcpy( (void*) &CoilEepromData, (const void*) &EepromCoil.aRxData[0], sizeof(Coil_Eeprom_Data_T) );



extern volatile Coil_Eeprom_Data_T  CoilEepromData; 
extern volatile Eeprom_Coil_T       EepromCoil;                         // control struct for the coil-eeprom  


typedef struct
{   
    UINT8   crcValueOut;
    UINT8   crcValueIn; 

    UINT8   pageAddress; 
    UINT8   dataLength;

    UINT8   bytesToTransmit;
    UINT8   bytesWritten;

    UINT8   bytesToReceive;    
    UINT8   bytesRead;    

    UINT8   errorCount;     
    bool    bWriteSucceed:1;
    bool    bStartup:1;  
    bool    bReadingStarted:1;
    UINT8   aTxData[COIL_SPI_BUFFER_SIZE];
    UINT8   aRxData[COIL_SPI_BUFFER_SIZE];
} Eeprom_Coil_T;
```

Comment: You don't need to cast to and from `void *` (in C).

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @Andre That's why it's a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. variables you copy are not declared, you only show some `typedef`s.

Comment: To me this is very unclear. How is `CoilEepromData` defined? How is `EepromCoil` defined and how is it initialized. What is the `power of 2` referring to?

Comment: @Olaf I have put the deceleration of the variable

Comment: @4386427 I have put the decelerations

Comment: What are `UINT8` etc.? Why not use the standard types? Your code invokes undefined behaviour. You violate effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. Use proper marshalling to/from the buffer, not just `memcpy`.

Comment: UINT8 is unsigned char. would you elaborate your comment as an answer. I didn't get it

Comment: The layout of `Coil_Eeprom_Data_T` must match the contents of `aRxData`. So `sizeof(Coil_Eeprom_Data_T)` should (probably) the same as `COIL_SPI_BUFFER_SIZE` (or at least less). Have you checked that? When doing stuff like this, use of a packed struct is very common - maybe look into that.

Comment: @4386427 that was the problem. please write it as answer. what do you mean by a packet struct ? can you show an example?

Comment: As I understand you've read the data from the EEPROM via a SPI and buffered that into EepromCoil.aRxData. In your code example any checks for the number of bytes read (if it's matching the size of the struct) are missing. You should check your struct size against the layout of the data in the eeprom / buffer. Your compiler may automatically align the data to defined borders based on your architecture.

Comment: @ChristianT that was exactly the problem. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what your comment about powers of two means, if that's a requirement you have to make it clearer.

Also, most casts to/from `void *` in C are not necessary, you shouldn't do them "just to be safe". It's hard to understand from your posted code why the casts are needed.

Finally, remember that structures are values too, you can use plain old assignment:

```
CoilEepromData.channel[0] = EepromCoil.aRxData[0];
CoilEepromData.channel[1] = EepromCoil.aRxData[1];
CoilEepromData.channel[2] = EepromCoil.aRxData[2];
```

The compiler might well optimize that into a single `memcpy()` call, but this is much better since it's more readable and easie to get right. You might want to put it in a loop to lessen the risk for indexing typos.

If you *really* want to use `memcpy()`, here's how:

```
memcpy(&CoilEepromData.channel[0], &EepromCoil.aRxData[0], sizeof CoilEepromData.channel[0]);
```

This uses `sizeof` on the destination variable, not on a type. This is a bit safer. Again, this would do well in a loop:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof CoilEepromData.channel / sizeof CoilEepromData.channel[0]; ++i)
  memcpy(&CoilEepromData.channel[i], &EepromCoil.aRxData[i], sizeof CoilEepromData.channel[i]);
```

The `sizeof` in the second part of the `for` header is to avoid hard-coding the array length. This is a bit scary since it requires that the length of both source and destination arrays be the same, of course.

Comment: in a loop ? so should I iterate over the buffers and do memcpy ?

Comment: I get that error line 407: cc0167:  error: argument
          of type "volatile ChannelData_T *" is incompatible with parameter of
          type "void *"
          memcpy(&CoilEepromData.channel[0], &EepromCoil.aRxData[0], sizeof CoilEepromData.channel[0]);

Comment: how would I do the loop please ? I didn't get your point. and how would I iterate over the data ? I don't know their sizes

Comment: @Andre *I get that error line 407: cc0167: error: argument of type "volatile ChannelData_T *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *" memcpy(&CoilEepromData.channel[0], &EepromCoil.aRxData[0], sizeof CoilEepromData.channel[0]);*  Your compiler isn't compliant with the C Standard, then.

Comment: I need help with the loop please, I didn't get it

Comment: @Andre *I casted it and it worked*  Exactly.  Casts to/from `void *` are not needed, per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **6.3.2.3 Pointers**: "A pointer to
`void`
may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.  A pointer to
any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a  pointer  to
`void`
and  back  again;  the  result  shall
compare equal to the original pointer."  Your compiler doesn't support that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You didn't show any `volatile` in your code.

Comment: @Andre: Do you get this incompatibility error for `memcpy()`'s 2nd argument only?

Comment: @alk for the first and the 2nd argument

Comment: @unwind I get that error  error: expression
          must have arithmetic type
         for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (CoilEepromData.channel / CoilEepromData.channel[0]); ++i)

Comment: @Andre Oops, that was a typo, there was a `sizeof` missing, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: "Also, never cast to/from void * in C, it's never necessary." This isn't really true, because of type qualifiers. Suppose you have `char* const` or `volatile char*` and want to pass it as second parameter to memcpy. Implicit conversions to/from `void*` only works if it leads to the same pointer type, or to a stricter qualified pointer type.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I didn't think about `volatile`. Thanks, and fixed.